# Estimate partial sum of binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients

$C^{m}_{n}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ are the binomial coefficients. Now for a fix $0<\alpha<1$, consider for any natural number $N$ the following sequence:
$$ T_N=\sum_{[\alpha N]\leq i\leq N}C^i_{N}$$
Could you help me with estimating the limit of $T_N/2^N$ when $N\to \infty$

Comment: I recall [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3832808) basically-the-same question (with my answer there giving a little bit *finer* result for $\alpha\neq1/2$). But the appearance of the sum makes me suspect that this is asked *many* times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(n)=\sum _{i=\lfloor n \alpha \rfloor }^n \binom{n}{i}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1) \, _2F_1(1,n (\alpha -1);n \alpha +1;-1)}{\Gamma (n-\alpha  n+1) \Gamma (n \alpha +1)}$$

From numerical results I got that
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{T(n)}{2^n}=\begin{cases}
1; & 0<\alpha<\frac12\\
\frac12;& \alpha=\frac12\\
0; &\frac12<\alpha<1\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't understand: according to your formula, $T(n) \leq 1$, which is apparently untrue.

Comment: I misread you sum  and inverted $i$ and $n$ because in $C^i_{N}$ I read $i$ high and $N$ low, like in $\binom{i}{N}$.