# The sum of the odd terms of partial combination numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have two following sums
$ S_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \binom{N}{2k-1}$,
$ S_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \binom{N}{2k}$. When $2K=N$, it is easy to obtain the results, however, is there a closed-form solution for $2K<N$? Or just a tight upper/lower bound? Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: This has been asked many times before, including by myself, and there is much to say about this. But the short answer is *"no"*.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering if there exists some special cases, e.x. $N = \delta K$, where $\delta$ is a constant, which have some closed-solutions or approximations.

Comment: @Servaes: well, some different rendering can be done ..of course it depends on what one wants to obtain and for which purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite the sums of interest as
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_{\,1}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K  {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   2\,k - 1 \cr}  \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{K - 1} {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   2\,k + 1 \cr}  \right)}   \cr 
  & S_{\,2}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\left( \matrix{  N \cr  2\,k \cr}  \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^K {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   2\,k \cr}  \right)}  - 1 = S_{\,0}  - 1 \cr} 
$$
Then consider that
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^K {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   2\,k \cr}  \right)x^{\,2k} }
  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{K - 1} {\left( \matrix{  N \cr   2\,k + 1 \cr}  \right)x^{\,2k + 1} }
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2K} {\left( \matrix{  N \cr  \,k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} } 
$$
Therefore we can concentrate on the Truncated Binomial
$$
B_{\,T} (z,r,m) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( \matrix{  r \cr  k \cr}  \right)z^{\,k} } 
\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;r \in R \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le m \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;z \in C \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
since therefrom we can retrieve the requested  sums as
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_{\,1}  = {{B_{\,T} (1,N,2K) - B_{\,T} ( - 1,N,2K)} \over 2}  \cr 
  & S_{\,2}  = {{B_{\,T} (1,N,2K) + B_{\,T} ( - 1,N,2K)} \over 2} - 1 \cr 
}
$$

The truncated binomial is just a simple polynomial of degree $m$ in $z$: no way to look for a "simpler" expression.
However it might be useful to "render" it in other forms, to show possible algebraic manipulations , specially
for asymptotics.
I will concisely resume some alternative representations in the following.

**a) Double o.g.f.**

We have that taking the o.g.f. both on $k$ and $m$
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & F_{\,a} (x,z,r)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le m \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr 
  \;z,x,r \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m} {\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\, \le \,m}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} } } \right)z^{\,m} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\, \le \,m}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   k \cr}  \right)
\left( \matrix{  m - k \cr   m - k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} z^{\,m} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,} {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   k \cr}  \right)\left( {zx} \right)^{\,\,k}
 \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m - k} {\left( \matrix{  m - k \cr   m - k \cr}  \right)z^{\,m - k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {1 - z}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   k \cr}  \right)\left( {zx} \right)^{\,k} }
  = {{\left( {1 + zx} \right)^{\,r} } \over {\left( {1 - z} \right)}} \cr} 
 } \tag {a.1}$$

Since the sum in $x^k$ is limited, it will converge for any value of $x$.
Concerning the sum in $z$ we consider it as a *formal sum*.
So
$$
B_{\,T} (z,r,m) = \left[ {z^{\,m} } \right]F_{\,a} (x,z,r)
$$

**b) Through the Beta  function**

The sum of the binomial truncated to $m$ can be given an integral representation which leads to the
[Incomplete Regularized Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   k \cr}  \right)x^{\,r - k} \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,k} }
  = \left( {r - m} \right)\left( \matrix{  r \cr   m \cr}  \right)\int_0^x {t^{\,r - m - 1} \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,m} dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {r - m} \right){{\Gamma (r + 1){\rm B}(x;\,r - m,m + 1)} \over {\Gamma (m + 1)\Gamma (r - m + 1)}}
 = {{{\rm B}(x;\,r - m,m + 1)} \over {{\rm B}(r - m,m + 1)}} =   \cr 
  &  = CDF\;Beta\;Distrib.\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;r,x \in \mathbb R \hfill \cr 
  \;x \in \left[ {0,1} \right] \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le m \in \mathbb Z < r \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
[re. to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3495189/317234)

Making the substitution
$$
{{1 - x} \over x} = y\quad  \Rightarrow \;\quad {1 \over {1 + y}}
 = x\quad \left| {\;x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]\; \leftrightarrow \;y \in \left[ {0,\infty } \right)} \right.
$$
we get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & B_{\,T} (y,r,m) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   k \cr}  \right)y^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {1 + y} \right)^{\,r} {{{\rm B}\left( {{1 \over {1 + y}};\,r - m,m + 1} \right)}
 \over {{\rm B}\left( {r - m,m + 1} \right)}}
 \quad \quad \left| \matrix{
  \,y \in \left[ {0,\infty } \right) \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le m \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr 
  \,\,0 \le m < r \in \mathbb R \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
 } \tag {b.1}$$

Yet, since the validity of the above is limited to non-negative values of $y$, it is not useful
to operate the bi-section.

**c) Through the Hypergeometric  function**

Either from the [expression of the Inc. Rat. Beta](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/BetaRegularized/26/01/02/)
wrt the Hypergeometric function, either directly we obtain
$$
\eqalign{
  & B_{\,T} (z,r,m) = \sum\limits_{k\, = \,0}^m
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr  k \cr}  \right)z^{\,k} }
  = z^{\,m} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   m - k \cr}  \right)\left( {{1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,m} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {{{r^{\,\underline {\,m - k\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,m - k\;} } }}\left( {{1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }
  = z^{\,m} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {{{r^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } \left( {r - m} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - k\,} } }
 \over {1^{\,\overline {\,m\;} } \left( {m + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - k\;} } }}\left( {{1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  r \cr   m \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {{{\left( {r - m} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - k\,} } } \over {\left( {m + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - k\;} } }}
 \left( {{1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  r \cr  m \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {{{m^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {r - m + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\;} } }}
 \left( {{1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  r \cr   m \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {{{\left( { - m} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\;} } } \over {\left( {r - m + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\;} } }}
 \left( { - {1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  r \cr   m \cr}  \right)
 {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{ { - m,\;1}  \cr  {r + 1 - m}  \cr } \;} \right|\; - {1 \over z}} \right) \cr} 
$$
where $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } ,\quad x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } $ represent
respectively the [Falling and Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).
Summarizing we have
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & B_{\,T} (z,r,m) = \sum\limits_{k\, = \,0}^m {\left( \matrix{  r \cr  k \cr}  \right)z^{\,k} }
  = z^{\,m} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   m - k \cr}  \right)\left( {{1 \over z}} \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  r \cr   m \cr}  \right){}_2F_{\,1}
 \left( {\left. {\matrix{  { - m,\;1}  \cr   {r + 1 - m}  \cr  } \;} \right|\; - {1 \over z}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {1 + z} \right)^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  r \cr   m \cr}  \right)
 {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{ { - m,\;r - m}  \cr {r + 1 - m}  \cr  } \;} \right|\;{1 \over {1 + z}}} \right)
 \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;z \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr 
  \;m \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr 
  \;r \notin \mathbb Z\; \vee \;m \le r \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
 } \tag {c.1}$$
where the last equivalent expression comes from the Beta function, as well as from one of the Pfaff transformations.
For the bisection we will use the first.

We can also directly express the bi-sected binomial as a ${}_3F_{\,2} $ Hypergeometric function.
Starting from
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   2k + p \cr}  \right)y^{\,2k + p} }
  = y^{\,2m + p} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\left( {\, \le \,m} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   2m + p - 2k \cr}  \right)\left( {y^{\, - 2} } \right)^{\,k} } 
$$
Putting
$$
t_{\,k}  = \left( \matrix{  r \cr  2m + p - 2k \cr}  \right)
 = {{r^{\,\underline {\,2m + p - 2k\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2k\,} } }}
$$
we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & t_{\,0}  = \left( \matrix{  r \cr  2m + p \cr}  \right)  \cr 
  & {{t_{\,k + 1} } \over {t_{\,k} }}
 = {{r^{\,\underline {\,2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} } }}
 {{1^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2k\,} } } \over {r^{\,\underline {\,2m + p - 2k\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( { - r} \right)^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} } }
 \over {\left( { - r} \right)^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2k\,} } }}
 {{1^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2k\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {1\, + 2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} \right)^{\,\overline {\,2\,} } }
 \over {\left( { - r\, + 2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} \right)^{\,\overline {\,2\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {2m + p - 1 - 2k\,} \right)\left( {\,2m + p - 2k\,} \right)}
  \over {\left( { - r\, + 2m + p - 2 - 2k\,} \right)\left( { - r\, + 2m + p - 1 - 2k\,} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {k - m - \left( {p - 1} \right)/2\,} \right)\left( {\,k - m - p/2\,} \right)}
 \over {\left( {k - m + \left( {r - p + 2} \right)/2\,} \right)\left( {k - m + \left( {r - p + 1} \right)/2\,} \right)}} \cr} 
$$
and so we get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m}
  {\left( \matrix{  r \cr  2k + p \cr}  \right)z^{\,2k + p} }  =   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,2m + p} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\left( {\, \le \,m} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{  r \cr   2m + p - 2k \cr}  \right)\left( {z^{\, - 2} } \right)^{\,k} }   \cr 
  &  = z^{\,2m + p} \left( \matrix{  r \cr   2m + p \cr}  \right)
 {}_3F_{\,2} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   { - m - \left( {p - 1} \right)/2,\; - m - p/2,\;1}  \cr 
   { - m + \left( {r - p + 2} \right)/2,\; - m + \left( {r - p + 1} \right)/2}  \cr 
 } \;} \right|\;{1 \over {z^{\,2} }}} \right) \cr 
  & \left| \matrix{
  \;z \in \mathbb R \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le m,\, p \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr 
  \;2m + p \le r \in \mathbb R \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
 } \tag {c.2}$$