# Bounding Binomial distribution tail

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

I have a random variable $X\sim \text{Bin}(3k, q)$ where $q < \frac{1}{2}$ and $q(1-q) \leq \frac{1}{5}$. I want to show that for $k=O(\log_2 r)$ I can bound the probability $\mathbb{P}(X\geq k)$ by $\frac{1}{2^r}$. I tried several upper bounds for the tails of binomial distributions I found online but none of them seems to do the trick.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the [exact formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) *(often used by [myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3495189))* $$\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant k)=k\binom{3k}{k}\int_0^q t^{k-1}(1-t)^{2k}\,dt$$ and the asymptotics for $q<1/3$ (which holds under your conditions on $q$) $$\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant k)\underset{k\to\infty}{\large\asymp}\frac12\sqrt{\frac3{k\pi}}\frac{1-q}{1-3q}\left(\frac{27}4q(1-q)^2\right)^k$$ (obtained using [Stirling's asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for $\binom{3k}{k}$ and [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) for the integral).

For $k=O(\log_2 r)$, this is definitely *not* $O(2^{-r})$, but rather $O(\color{blue}{r^{-\alpha}}\log^{-1/2}r)$ with $$\alpha=2-\log_2\big(27q(1-q)^2\big)\color{gray}{\big[{}>0\big]}.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have asked a more specific question about my problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517879/bounding-probability-of-error-for-repeated-iteration-of-algorithm).

Comment: @metamorphy could you explain how exactly you use Laplace's method in this case? I tried to get the details right but I have some extra terms that are not present in your answer. In particular, a $(2k)!$ that appears from Stirling's approximation.

Also, I am trying to obtain a similar asymptotic when we have any $n$ instead of $3k$. Do you think your approach can be used for that case?