# Bounding probability of error for repeated iteration of algorithm

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have an algorithm that gives either one of the two correct answers for a problem with probability $1-q = \frac{8}{\pi^2}$. I want to show that if we run this algorithm $O(\log_2 r)$ times and consider the most frequently occurring result as our answer then this will be correct with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{2^r}$.

My initial thought was to bound the probability of error by the probability of our algorithm returning the wrong answer in at least one-third of the runs. That is, we can model the algorithm runs as independent random variables $X_i \sim \text{Be}(q)$ and say that the probability of error in $3k$ runs is at most
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3k} X_i\geq k\right)$$

The sum of $X_i$ follows the Binomial distribution $\text{Bin}(3k, q)$. I have asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517653/bounding-binomial-distribution-tail) question related to my problem but the answer given there suggests this approach won't yield the bound I'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @kodlu There are two correct answers to the problem and our algorithm is indeed considered successful if it selects one of the two after the majority vote. I don't quite understand the second part of your comment, though.

Comment: @kodlu I think it matters because if we had, say, $3$ correct answers then the bound I am proposing wouldn't work. The idea here is that for our algorithm to select a wrong answer after the majority vote the total number of incorrect outcomes have to be at least one-third of the total outcomes.

Comment: clear now. I will try to have a look when I can

Comment: @kodlu Thank you!

Comment: I have an updated answer, did you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Unfortunately no. There is an exponential lower bound to the fail probability of the form
$$
P_{fail}\geq 2^{-0.3 n+\epsilon n}
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ can be made arbitrarily small. This means that if you use $\log r$ repeats your error probability is lower bounded by $1/\mathrm{poly}(r).$

Details:

Let $q=1-\frac{8}{\pi^2}\approx 0.19$ be the probability that the algorithm *does not* output one of the two right answers. So the probability of majority vote not working is the same as the probability that more than two thirds of the answers are wrong. So the probability of failure is:
$$
P_{fail}=\sum_{k+1\leq i} \binom{3k}{i} q^i (1-q)^{3k-i} =
\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{Bin}(3k,q)\geq k+1).
$$
Let us lower bound the dominant term in the binomial sum which is the term $\binom{n}{k}$ where $k=f(qn)$ where $f$ is the nearest integer function. Use the lower bound (see the answer to this mathoverflow question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236508/are-there-good-bounds-on-binomial-coefficients/236511#236511)) but take the entropy in bits so the exponential is to the base 2:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{n}{8k(n-k)}}2^{nh(k/n)} \leq \binom{n}{k}
\quad(\ast) 
$$
dividing by $2^n$ to obtain a probability we get (with $h(\cdot)$ the binary entropy function
$$
P_{fail}\geq \sqrt{\frac{n}{8k(n-k)}}2^{n(h(k/n)-1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{{8nq(1-q)}}}2^{-n(1-h(q))}
$$
or plugging in $q=0.19,$
$$
P_{fail}\geq \exp_2\left\{-0.3 n -\frac{1}{2}\log_2(1.2312 n) \right\}\gg 
\exp_2\left\{-0.3 n+\epsilon n\right\} 
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ can be made arbitrarily small by taking $n$ large enough.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Did you mean to write $\mathbb{P}(\text{Bin}(3k,q)\geq k)$? We need more than $1/3$ of the answers to be incorrect for the majority vote to fail, not less.